# How can i save my current cursor position in Visual Studio Code (VS Code), so that i can come back to it quickly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to save my current cursor position, move to some other line (in the same file), do some editing and jump back to the original cursor position to continue coding.

Lets say i am in line 50 and realise i need to add a header/library file at line 5. I want save my position here so that i can jump back after making my changes at line 5. How can i do this?

I have looked into cursor navigation shortcuts but they all move cursor by tracing every position cursor was in, and its time consuming and confusing, instead i want to jump back to saved position in one shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [selection anchor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_accessibility).  There is no default keybinding for "Go to Selection Anchor" so you'd have to add one yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, based on [selection anchor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_accessibility), and [multi command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension, i wrote a keybinding which will solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in command for that. The `Go Back` / `Go Forward` navigation commands doesn't allows you to *save* specific locations.

Instead, you should rely on extensions, like my [Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks) extensions.

There is a bunch of other similar extensions, as you can see on this search https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=bookmarks&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance. You should take a look at some, and try out the one that better fit our needs.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the extension. Its seems really helpful. But for this specific case i wrote a keybinding based on the [multi command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension, which solves my issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@scottfrazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17637/scottfrazer) for the suggesting [selection anchor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_accessibility).

Thanks [@alefragnani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758872/alefragnani) for suggesting extensions.

Based on these answers, i wrote a keybinding using [multi command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension,

After installing the [multi command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension,
Add the following snippets in the keybindings.json,

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+`",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "when": "!selectionAnchorSet",
        "args": { 
            "sequence": [
                "editor.action.setSelectionAnchor",
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+`",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "when": "selectionAnchorSet",
        "args": { 
            "sequence": [
                "editor.action.goToSelectionAnchor",
                "editor.action.cancelSelectionAnchor",
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

Above snippet will create a key binding for "ctrl+alt+`" (Ctrl + Alt + BackTick).

When pressed,

1. Creates a selection anchor at cursor position
2. If an anchor already exists, Move to that cursor position and deletes that anchor at that position.